# random signals through LTI systems, why are these two signals joint wide sense stationary?

Tags: linear-systems, random-process, stationary

I’m trying to solve this problem but I don’t understand an assumption the solution makes: 
**The question:** 
let $\hat{W}$ be the best linear approximation of $W_t$ out of $Y_t$, find $\text{CoV}(W_4, \hat{W_8})$. it’s also given that  $$Y(t) = (h * W)(t) + (g* Z)(t)$$ where for this sub question $h(t) = g(t) = \delta (t)$. $$S_W(f) = \begin{cases} N_0 & |f|< A,\\ 0 & \text{otherwise}\end{cases}$$ $$S_Z(f) = \begin{cases} N_1 & |f|<2A,\\  0 & \text{otherwise} \end{cases}$$
$N_0 > N_1 \quad  N_0,N_1,A,b >0$

**The assumption:** $W$ and $\hat{W}$ are joint wide sense stationary (cross correlation only depends on the time differences)

why is that the case here?

**additional details** - i've been told the question is lacking in details, I don't know which details are missing so I'll translate the whole question the subquestion I'm struggling with came from.

$$ H(f) = f \quad G(f) = \frac{1- ibf}{1 + b^2 f^2}$$
$$ Y(t) = (h * W)(t) + (g* Z)(t)$$
$Z(t)$ and $W(t)$ are independent wide sense stationary process with expectation 0 and SPD:
$$S_W(f) = \begin{cases} N_0 & |f|< A,\\ 0 & \text{otherwise}\end{cases}$$ $$S_Z(f) = \begin{cases} N_1 & |f|<2A,\\  0 & \text{otherwise} \end{cases}$$
$N_0 > N_1 \quad  N_0,N_1,A,b >0$
**a.** Find $E(Y^2(t))$ (i understood how to do that) 
it is now given that $h(t) = g(t)  = \delta (t)$. we'll define $H_1(f)$ to be the linear optimal filter for $Z(t)$ out of $\{Y(t)\}$, and denote it's output $\hat{Z}(t)$. 
**b.** show that $E(\hat{Z}^2(t)) < \tfrac{3}{4}E(Z^2(t))$ (i did this too). 
**c.** let $\hat{W}$ be the output of the optimal linear filter that approximates/estimates $W$ out of $\{Y(t)\}$. find $\text{CoV}(W_4, \hat{W_8})$ **<this is where I'm struggling**

Comment: I vote to close this question since there are too many details that are left unspecified, and without these, the question is impossible to answer.

Comment: I’ll add them - what details are those?

Comment: I added details